# Create a list of lists with increasing numbers in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

When given a starting number and an increment, I want to be able to create a lists of lists in Haskell.

For example:

```
>listIncrease 5 3
[[5], [5,6], [5,6,7]]
```

I have tried using a recursive function but I haven't been able to get the function just right.

This is what I currently have:

```hs
listIncrease :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
listIncrease a 0 = []
listIncrease a b = [[a..a+b-1], (listIncrease a (b-2))]
```

I know this won't work because of the base case and because of the base case being incorrect, and the recursive step because you can't take an [[Int]] to be an [Int].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
listIncrease :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
listIncrease a b = [[a..i] | i <- [a..a+b-1]]
```

To understand why this works, consider evaluating the outer layers for your example of 5 and 3: `[[5..i] | i <- [5..7]]`, `[[5..i] | i <- [5,6,7]]`, and then `[[5..5], [5..6], [5..7]]`.

Comment: Very nice answer. Covers all

Comment: This outputs your list: take 3 [ [5..n] | n <- [5..] ]

Answer (score 6):

We can construct a range with:

```
[5 .. 7]
```

to create the final list we want:

```
Prelude> [5 .. 7]
[5,6,7]
```

We can then use [**`inits :: [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits) to generate all prefixes:

```
Prelude Data.List> inits [5 .. 7]
[[],[5],[5,6],[5,6,7]]
```

We can use [**`drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop) to omit the first element.

We can thus implement `listIncrease` as:

```
import Data.List(inits)

listIncrease :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> a -> [[a]]
listIncrease lo n = drop 1 (inits [lo .. lo + n - 1])
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> listIncrease 7 0
[]
Prelude Data.List> listIncrease 7 1
[[7]]
Prelude Data.List> listIncrease 7 2
[[7],[7,8]]
Prelude Data.List> listIncrease 7 3
[[7],[7,8],[7,8,9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard library function just for this - `inits`. It returns all possible prefixes of a list, including the empty one:

```
> inits ['a', 'b', 'c']
[[], ['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

To get what you need, you just have to drop the first empty list, and you're done:

```
listIncrease a n = drop 1 $ inits [a .. (a+n-1)]
```

Comment: Lol, we wrote nearly exact the same answer at nearly the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option involving `inits`: create an *infinite* list of ranges, drop the first (empty) range, then take the next `n` elements:

```
listIncrease from n = take n (tail (inits [from..]))
```

---

This even has a nearly readable point-free version:

```
listIncrease = flip take . tail . inits . enumFrom
```

A quick explanation, showing the type of each step and an example using 5 and 3 as the arguments:

- `enumFrom :: Enum a => a -> [a]` produces `[5..]`
- `inits . enumFrom :: Enum a => a -> [[a]]` produces `[[],[5],[5,6],[5,6,7],...]`
- `tail . inits . enumFrom :: Enum a => a -> [[a]]` produces `[[5],[5,6],[5,6,7],...]`
- `flip take . tail . inits . enumFrom :: Enum a => a -> Int -> [[a]]` produces a function call `(flip take) [[5],[5,6],[5,6,7],...] 3 == take 3 [[5],[5,6],[5,6,7],...] == [[5],[5,6],[5,6,7]]`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the cleanest recursive implementation:

```
listIncrease :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
listIncrease a 0 = []
listIncrease a b = map (a:) $ [] : listIncrease (a + 1) (b - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with traditional pattern matching you can try:

```
listIncrease :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
listIncrease a 0 = []
listIncrease a 1 = [[a]]
listIncrease a b = reverse $ ([a..a+b-1] : [a..a+b-2] : (listIncrease a (b-2)))
```

since the number could be odd and also you are making two steps each recursion, you should add the extra patter when the number its `1` , and reverse the list to has the desire order.

An optimized version using Sequence should be:

```
import Data.Sequence ((|>), empty, fromList)
import Data.Foldable (toList)

listIncrease :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
listIncrease a b = toList (fromSeq a b)

fromSeq a 0 = empty
fromSeq a 1 = fromList([[a]])
fromSeq a b = (fromSeq a (b-2)) |> [a..a+b-2] |> [a..a+b-1]
```